# Cannot bind POST body to URL in Go

Tags: go, post, bind

I'm trying to make a simple API call to the pokemon API through reaching a POST request that I'm serving with Echo.

I'm sending a POST request to "localhost:8000/pokemon" with the body `{ "pokemon": "pikachu" }` where the BODY is reattached to the request through ioutil changing the request to be made with the body: "localhost:8000/pokemon/pikachu".

The POST request works by responding with some JSON, but the call being made is only to "localhost:8000/pokemon", and it seems the body isn't added to the URL.

I think there is something wrong with the binding here `u := new(pokemon)`

Anyone have any ideas?

```
func main() {
    e := echo.New() // Middleware
    e.Use(middleware.Logger()) // Logger
    e.Use(middleware.Recover())
    //CORS
    e.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
        AllowOrigins: []string{"*"},
        AllowMethods: []string{echo.GET, echo.HEAD, echo.PUT, echo.PATCH, echo.POST, echo.DELETE},
    }))
    // Root route => handler
    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!\n")
    })
    e.POST("/pokemon", controllers.GrabPrice) // Price endpoint
    // Server
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8000"))
}
```

```
type pokemon struct { pokemon string `json:"pokemon" form:"pokemon" query:"pokemon"`
}
// GrabPrice - handler method for binding JSON body and scraping for stock price
func GrabPrice(c echo.Context) (err error) {
    // Read the Body content
    var bodyBytes []byte
    if c.Request().Body != nil {
        bodyBytes, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request().Body)
    }
    // Restore the io.ReadCloser to its original state
    c.Request().Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))
    u := new(pokemon)

    er := c.Bind(u) // bind the structure with the context body
    // on no panic!
    if er != nil {
        panic(er)
    }

    // company ticker
    ticker := u.pokemon
    print("Here", string(u.pokemon))
    // yahoo finance base URL
    baseURL := "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"
    print(baseURL + ticker)
    // price XPath
    //pricePath := "//*[@name=\"static\"]"
    // load HTML document by binding base url and passed in ticker
    doc, err := htmlquery.LoadURL(baseURL + ticker)
    // uh oh :( freak out!!
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // HTML Node
        // from the Node get inner text
    price := string(htmlquery.InnerText(doc))
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, price)
}
```

Comment: You need to export the fields. i.e. `type pokemon struct { Pokemon string ... }`

Comment: As @mkopriva mentions if your struct doesn't have exported fields the binding engine can't access them to match their tags to the ones in the body so no binding can happen. In some IDE's using structs with unexported fields will show you a warning or error if you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what already answered by @mkopriva and @A.Lorefice

Yes you need to ensure that the variable are exported, for the binding to work properly.
Since underlay process of binding actually using reflection mechanism on the struct. See [this](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection#Structs) documentation, scroll into Structs section to see what it is.

```
type pokemon struct { 
    Pokemon string `json:"pokemon" form:"pokemon" query:"pokemon"`
}
```